# In Python how to select rows that contain duplicate items in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing lists such as:

```
rowdata = [['100004100', 'ABC1234AS', '45.96'],
           ['100004101', 'ABC1234AS', '104.95'],
           ['100004103', '453SDFAS', '24.52']]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to return the first value and third value as a group if the second value matches.

The first value is an order number, the second value is a batch number and the third is the dollar amount. My credit card processor batches random orders together. I'm trying to find the rows where the batch number matches and return the order numbers and amounts for those lines.

I'm thinking something like,

```
for item in rowdata:
    if item[1] is a duplicate:
        print item[0], item[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has some pretty helpful builtin tools, but sometimes they can be hard to find if you don't know what to look for.  Here [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) are helpful.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

rowdata = [['100004100', 'ABC1234AS', '45.96'],
           ['100004101', 'ABC1234AS', '104.95'],
           ['100004103', '453SDFAS', '24.52']]

for key, group in groupby(rowdata, itemgetter(1)):
    print key, list(group)
```

Gives you:

> ABC1234AS [['100004100', 'ABC1234AS', '45.96'], ['100004101','ABC1234AS', '104.95']]
>
> 453SDFAS [['100004103', '453SDFAS', '24.52']]

Answer (score 1):

```
rowdata = [['100004100', 'ABC1234AS', '45.96'],
           ['100004101', 'ABC1234AS', '104.95'],
           ['100004103', '453SDFAS', '24.52']]

def find_duplicates(duplicate):
    return [(item[0], item[2]) for item in rowdata if item[1] == duplicate]

print find_duplicates('ABC1234AS')
```

Prints:

```
[('100004100', '45.96'), ('100004101', '104.95')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to group the orders by the batch number you could use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
rowdata = [['100004100', 'ABC1234AS', '45.96'],
           ['100004101', 'ABC1234AS', '104.95'],
           ['100004103', '453SDFAS', '24.52']]

batches = defaultdict(list)

for order in rowdata:
    batches[order[1]].append([order[0], order[2]])

for batch, orders in batches.iteritems():
    print "%s: %s" % (batch, orders)
```

Outputs:

```
ABC1234AS: [['100004100', '45.96'], ['100004101', '104.95']]
453SDFAS: [['100004103', '24.52']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
rowdata = [['100004100', 'ABC1234AS', '45.96'], ['100004101', 'ABC1234AS', '104.95'], ['100004103','453SDFAS', '24.52']]

bucket = defaultdict(list)
for col1, col2, col3 in rowdata:
    bucket[col2].append((col1,col3))

duplicates = {key:value for key, value in bucket.items() if len(value) > 1}

print (duplicates)
```

Prints the following:

> > {'ABC1234AS': [('100004100', '45.96'), ('100004101', '104.95')]}

Working example: http://ideone.com/RBJjh5